# OctoberCMS Multiple morphOne Relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, octobercms

I have a polymorphic Image Model (`public $morphTo = ['imageable' => []];`) and a Post Model that uses it.

I want the Post to have 2 o 3 Images for very different purposes (Post Header, Featured Image and Background Image)

Due the complexity of the Image model handling images and its use on several other classes (Articles, Pages, etc) I would like very much to use it on Posts like this, but one image of each type, that's why I use `morphOne`. Did so like this on `Post` Model:

```
public $morphOne = [
    'header_image' => [
        Image::class,
        'name' => 'imageable'
    ],
    'featured_image' => [
        Image::class,
        'name' => 'imageable'
    ],
    'background_image' => [
        Image::class,
        'name' => 'imageable'
    ],
];
```

But recovering the image seems to always retrieve the first in the image table even having both saved there. Saving any replaces the first record, deleting deletes the first record, etc ...

I can guess the problem, probably retrieving ONE record for the MorphOne relationship gets the first that matches the `type`and the `id` for the imageable attribute.

The question is: Is there a way to make this structure work ? Parameters on relation, maybe a different morph relationship ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: never tried octobercms (yet - but had few laravel background) i wonder what will happen if you gave it different name, `'name' => 'imageable'`. **Edit** or perhaps, give additional column (if possible) to the image table, just like [in this example](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/multiple-polymorphic-relations-on-one-model).

Comment: Implemented practically this same solution on october using relationship conditions. See my answer below!

Comment: i see, its an interesting way to manipulate polymorphic relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to use multiple morphOne relationships.

You just need to add a scope or conditions to the relationship and a column to filter the data:

```
public function scopeHeaderImage($query) {
    $query->where('image_type', "header_image");
}

public function scopeFeaturedImage($query) {
    $query->where('image_type', "featured_image");
}
```

And on the Relationship:

```
public $morphOne = [
    'header_image' => [
        \NewCriterion\Content\Models\Image::class,
        'name' => 'imageable',
        'scope' => 'headerImage'
    ],
    'featured_image' => [
        \NewCriterion\Content\Models\Image::class,
        'name' => 'imageable',
        'conditions' => "image_type = 'featured_image'"
    ]
];
```

*Both ways are valid, as scope (using the model method on top or directly using a raw where condition)*

Note that, for this to work properly, you must save this info on the database. I, for one implemented it in the `$model->beforeFilter()`:

```
$model->header_image->image_type = "header_image";
$model->featured_image->image_type = "featured_image";
```